# Add a method to Number throws exception

Tags: javascript

I am reading javascripts the good parts and was testing out a code.

```html
Number.method('integer', function ( ) {
 document.writeln("called"+ this<0);
return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
});
```

and testing it by calling it as

```
document.writeln((-10 / 3).integer());
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Math[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function` error. Am i doing something wrong? I am testing it on chrome

I forgot to mention, there is another method added to function.protoype as

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
 this.prototype[name] = func;
 return this;
};
```

Comment: Just a little tip: in 2016 there's little reason to debug with `document.write...` calls. Please get to know the console and its API: `console.log()`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `Math.ceiling()`, but `Math.ceil()`. 
Probably this is generating the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Math[(intermediate value)(intermediate
>   value)(intermediate value)] is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the prototype of Number

```
Number.prototype.integer = function ( ) 
{
    document.writeln("called"+ this<0);
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
};
```

Adding to the prototype make sure that instance of Number will have this property not the Number object only.

Also, try to avoid `document.writeln` since it will basically wipe-off the existing document removing the existing events. Use `document.body.innerHTML` if required.

```
Number.prototype.integer = function ( ) 
{
    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>called"+ (this<0);
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this); //observe that ceiling is also replaced with ceil since there is no such method called ceiling
};
```

Comment: There is no method `Math.ceiling()`, but `Math.ceil()`.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin ya that actually fixed it , thanks . it was the ceiling that was causing the problem

Comment: @Sam Interesting. Ok, I put it as an answer below.